# Photoshop: how to save my panel arrangement as default

Tags: adobe-photoshop, workspace

Every time when I open Photoshop, I get this panel arrangement:

[image]

Every time I set it to this arrangement:

[image]

But every time I must set again.

Can someone tell me how to save the arrangement to make it the default?

Answer (score 6):

1. Arrange your windows as needed
2. Go to Window > Workspace > New workspace
3. Read more at https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/workspace-basics.html

[image: new workspace]